# Matrix inverse quesiton

Tags: matrices

It's known that set of invertible matrices is dense in $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ and that the function taking an invertible matrix to its inverse is continuous. Given this, shouldn't we be able to define an inverse for any matrix by $A$ by taking $A_n\to A$ and then defining $A^{-1}=lim A_n^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under this definition, what would be the inverse of the zero matrix? If we take $A_n$ to be the diagonal matrix with entries $1/n$ along the diagonal, then these converge to the zero matrix. But
$$
A_n^{-1} =  \begin{pmatrix}
n & 0 \\ 
0 & n 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
does not converge as $n \to \infty$.